# How to compare column to column within one partition

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 7 columns (ID and dates). I need to check if the values rise from the left side of the table.

[image]

What I need to do is to compare '2012-07-13' to values in another columns within one partition (sp_id). So e.g I've got to compare '2012-07-13' to '2014-09-01' (the same row) but also '2017-03-12' (the row below). Do you think that there's a solution to do it efficently without a cursor?

Comment: Have you looked at `Lead`/`'Lag`?

Comment: @HABO the problem is that one partition may have more then 2 rows, this example is a little bit misleading.